# Netty Server. Is it possible to Accept Rest Requests like POST/GET

Tags: netty, netty-socketio

I have create a  microservice with springboot that accepts REST POST/GET etc. I want to forword  the payload to a socket client. Therefore i have use Netty framework. My question is :
Is it possible for Netty ( Server )to accept a REST POST/GET request and forword it to a netty socket client.
My implementation is like this. I receive the Request from REST and send it  on a  Netty client inside the microservice. Then i forword it to a Netty server inside the microservice to send it to a different client. (Tomcat runs on 8080 and Netty server on 8090). I am unsure if this is correct and its possible for the server to accept direct Rest requests ? If there is a tutorial also would be a great help.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implement  something similar. What i did is i have create a client inside the microservice and send the message to server. Transform Rest to socket.

If there is an other solution I don't know about it and I am curious to find out(please share).
But this works. Just create a netty client inside the microservice and you can pass the data.